# Python: Efficient way to prepend a space in a string before of upper case letter

Tags: python

What is the best way to convert the following string to the expected string in Python.

1. `"PowerEdgeSystem"` => `Power Edge System`
2. `"VMwareSystem"`    => `VMware System`
3. `VMwareSystemEQUIPMENT` => `VMware System EQUIPMENT`

Tried:

```
s = 'PowerEdgeSystem'
s = ''.join([' ' + c if i != 0 and c.isupper() else c for i, c in enumerate(s)])
```

First string is fine, but not as good for second string. Still we can check the case of 'both' side of the particular character and add space based on that as below,

```
s = ''.join([' ' + c if i != 0 and c.isupper() and not c[i+1].isupper() else c for i, c in enumerate(s)])
```

But the code will become more messy. I'm expecting some thing more clear way (if anything available).
Thank you,

Comment: Your solution works?

Comment: @wwii "But the code will become more messy" OP is looking for cleaner / better solution.  which I think is reasonable.

Comment: Other than the learning experience for better way, if you have a solution that doesn't seem intuitive generally I'd recommend just putting it in a function and well document it, so calls to the function are clean and the documentation of the function is clean, then the body of the function can be messy as you need it to be.

Comment: `i` is undefined?

Comment: second code now results in index out of range because `c` is of length 1, and `i+1` > 0 - Do you mean `s = ''.join([' ' + c if i != 0 and c.isupper() and i+1<len(s) and not s[i+1].isupper() else c for (i,c) in enumerate(s)])` ? Even that does not produce the expected results `VMware System`.

Comment: @Ruzihm Corrected, Pl add `i, ` after `for` keyword, For second code we have to add Exception handler also, so that asked for an efficient method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with substitution for this, greedily matching at least one non-uppercase character followed by at least one uppercase character, then inserting a space in between:

```
>>> matchPattern = r"([^A-Z]+)([A-Z]+)"
>>> replacePattern = r"\1 \2"
>>> re.sub(matchPattern, replacePattern, "VMwareSystemVMwareSystem")
'VMware System VMware System'
>>> re.sub(matchPattern, replacePattern, "PowerEdgeSystem")
'Power Edge System'
```

Comment: Working for `VMwareSystemEQUIPMENT` too.

Comment: @JaiK If this answer helped please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

I think you will want something like this, using [Regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWord")
'Word Word Word'
```

Unfortunately this does not succeed on `"VMwareSystem"`.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "VMwareSystem")
'V Mware System'
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Hint: try with both of asker's prompts

Comment: I tested it again on Repl.it and works fine:
import re |
word = 'PowerEdgeSystem' |
word2 = re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", word) |
print(word2)

Comment: @JoséHenriqueRoveda It doesn't work for `VMwareSystem` (though it's not clear how one could handle that case without some semantic knowledge).

Comment: I clarified that this is a partial answer, and included where it falls short.